# Distance between two coordinates in a column to a matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"site" : [1,2,3,4,5], "coordiantes":[(35.786827, -77.884923),(35.643, -77.3165),(35.669927, -77.385737),(36.0096, -77.8117),(34.971758, -80.387936)]})
```

I want to get a matrix dataframe with distance among all sites

```
Site  Site1  Site2  Site3 Site4 Site5
Site1   0      2      2     4    5
Site2    1     0      4
Site3
Site4
Site5                                     ..... So on.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def distance(i1, i2):
    return math.sqrt((i1[0] - i2[0])**2 + (i1[1] - i2[1])**2)

for i in df['site']:
    df[i] = None
df = df.set_index('site')

for k1, v1 in df.iterrows():
    for k2, v2 in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[k1, k2] = distance(v1['coordinates'], v2['coordinates'])

df = df.drop(columns='coordinates')    
df

             1         2         3         4         5
site                                                  
1          0.0  0.586337  0.512691  0.234498  2.632378
2     0.586337       0.0  0.074289  0.616132  3.143928
3     0.512691  0.074289       0.0  0.544814  3.082311
4     0.234498  0.616132  0.544814       0.0  2.777428
5     2.632378  3.143928  3.082311  2.777428       0.0
```

If your `coordinates` are the geographical ones, you need to redefine `distance`.